# Cannot create simplenews content

Tags: 7, emails

I have simplenews module installed on drupal 7.50

[image: modules installed]

When accessing **#overlay=node/add/simplenews**

I get a NOT FOUND, so I cannot create any newsletter content. Tried to flush cache but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You are getting "page not found" or "access denied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested on Drupal vanilla installation 7.50 and simplenews version 7.x-1.1 stable release, the link works perfect to add simplenews nodes.

I would recommend you

```
 -  Re install simplenews module
 -  Check if you see simplenews content type under structure>>content types
 -  Check if you see any error in your error logs.
 -  Check if you are using dev version of simplenews module
```

Comment: Thanks, reinstall worked... don't know why it didn't in first place.